# Как подсчитать время простоя сервисов в Prometheus+Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Столкнулся с задачей, выводить время простоя сервисов за 30 дней в Grafane из Prometheus. Запрос в Prometheus делаю вот так(первое число это количество опросов сервиса за 30 дней, в минуту делается 12 запросов) ((518400)-sum_over_time(up{instance="https://example.com"}[30d]))/12/60.
В Prometheus отдает время в часах, по формуле все правильно. Но в Grafana делая тот же вопрос, я получаю погоду.
Опыта в Prometheus нет большого. Подскажите почему Grafana выдает погоду и если есть варианты, то как изменить формулу.
Заранее спасибо.

```
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/H40yN.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем ясно какой плагин вы используете в Графане. Думаю именно из-за него или его настроек показывает погоду. Возможно в настройках плагина нужно разбираться.

Ваша формула работает в Графане(плагин к примеру Stat), главное в конце нужна еще одна скобка ")".

Вот хорошая статья для подсчета времени онлайн и оффлайн (https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/PrometheusCountUsageOverTime). Можно немного модифицировать вашу формулу
((5184000 - sum_over_time(up{instance="https://example.com"}[30d]))/12/60)

чтобы получилось вот так: 
43200 - sum_over_time(up{instance="https://example.com"}[30d:1m]) где можно сразу выставить шаг забора метрик по минутно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылку на статью. Я смог на днях добиться корректного ответа. А может еще сможете подсказать. Хочу считать не только время простоя, но и сколько было таких инцидентов за промежуток времени(рисунок добавил к вопросу). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Наверное не совсем понимаю сложности вопроса, но разве sum_over_time(метрика[30d]) не считает?

Comment: Мне не общие время сейчас нужно, а количество раз. Вот сработал у меня ALERT(не работает сервис, например два часа). И вот эти 2 часа это 1 инцидент. Следующий ALERT(например 3 часа) случились через 2 недели, это второй инцидент. И вот я хочу, чтобы я мог считать количество этих инцидентов. Спасибо.

Comment: Извиняюсь за то что долго не отвечал. Просто задача, которую ты хочешь решить не совсем простая. Обшарил иностранные сайты и ничего не нашел толком кроме совета "не усложнять")) Но если дальше добивать я бы предложил создать новую метрику(новый rule) примерно такого вида new_metric = ALERTS{alertname="xx"} + 0*absent(ALERTS{alertname="xx"}) чтобы она четко показывала когда есть мети уже на ней считать количество ресетов (resets(new_metric[1h]) 
не уверен, что получится, но пока нет времени проверить. Если получится отпишусь
с уважением

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за помощь. Я вот пытался переписываться(со своим уровнем английского). Я так понимаю вот такой же примерно вариант предложили. Но пока не получился, либо я не правильно делаю, хотя сказали правильно.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630701/prometheus-count-metric-value-over-a-period-of-time